# Mod_Rewrite to show only last subcategory in URL

Tags: categories, permalinks, htaccess, slug, mod-rewrite

I have a website with a three-tier hierarchy of categories: `Main category> Subcategory> Second Level Subcategory`. In the URL I would like to get only the currently selected category displayed. So the first or the first two category levels should not appear in the URL. For a better understanding:

If a user navigates to a main category, the category will be displayed.
If a user navigates to a sub category, only this subcategory will be displayed in the url.
If a user navigates to a second level subcategory, only this second level category will be displayed in the url.

I'm pretty sure that there must be a **mod_rewrite** to handle this, but i can't find any.

Can someone here help me with that?

Comment: Solved it! It's in functions.php.

Comment: add_filter('category_link', 'no_category_parents',1000,2);
function no_category_parents($catlink, $category_id) {
$category = &get_category( $category_id );
if ( is_wp_error( $category ) )
return $category;
$category_nicename = $category->slug;
$catlink = trailingslashit(get_option( 'home' )) . user_trailingslashit( $category_nicename, 'category' );
return $catlink;
}